# PHP: Link Videos

Tags: php, templates

Hi and thank you for stopping by, Let me get to my question.

I'm currently working on my website, 90% of my page is made with .php.
Im using php template to keep the same design for all my pages.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is that when a user click on any video link I want to send that user to my video.php where all that video will share that same layout.

Example of what I want to do :

## http://ilpvideo.com/

You see, every video link will open up the same page but different video and the contents related to the video.

How can I make all my video open up on my video.php template?
I try google and youtube trying to find at least basic guide on how to do it, but I can't find anything.

Sorry for my bad English and for asking here instead of showing code, but i have no idea where to start.

My index.php

```
<a href="video.php?id=video1">
<image src="/local/images/vid_01.jpg">
</a>
```

my video.php

```
$video1 = $_GET['video1'];
<section id="video-php">
<iframe src="media/<?php $video1 ?>"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="frame-info">
<?php echo "$page_view Views"?>
<p>I'm yelling Timber!</p>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: show what code you have and where you are confused?

Comment: This is my index.php code
:
<div class="thumbnail">
 <a href="video.php?id=video1">
 <img src="/local/images/vid_01.jpg">
</a>
</div>

Here is my video.php:

$video = $_GET['id'];
<iframe src="media/<?php $video?>"  allowfullscreen></iframe>


Now when i click on that link on my index.php it tranfer me to video.php and i get this message.




Index of /local/media

[ICO] Name Last modified Size Description
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory   -  
[VID] video1.mp4 2016-01-20 20:22 2.2M

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vo93k3gb/

Comment: I guess if u not a professional developer you get no help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like this in the videos page for all the videos add the link with the id of the video.

```
<a href='video.php?id=video1'>video1</a>
```

In video.php use get variable to know which file you are accessing.

```
$video = $_GET['id'];
```

using the database:
if you store the video names in the database, you can use the id, to retrieve the data from the database and you can use the filename and location from the database.

If you are not using the database, store all the videos in a folder, and pass the filename in the id, so that it contains the video filename.

Example using video tag:

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="<?=$video?>.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="<?=$video?>.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: I'm a bit new to php, i will explain what i understood from your post. also Thank you for replying.

 Example i have my index.pph with a link to
 <a href="video.php?id=video1">Click here for video</a>.
 
Now that user will be direct to my video.php on top of my video.php
 i will make a variable $video = $_GET['id'];

Comment: now on my iframe i will do
<iframe src="<?php $video; ?>">

I'm i correct here, if not can you link me to some resource or break it down for me a little bit more.

Again. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Yeah that's it. I have edited the post.. using video tag

Comment: i let you know if it work. Thank you!

Comment: WOW!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! now i understand! THANK YOU! @sandyclone
I'm mad i can't give you a +1.